# How to modify UITextField in FirstViewController from SecondViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

So I am fairly new to objective C and iOS programming. I am learning as I program and have a question. I am trying to modify a `UITextField` in my FirstViewController with my Second. How do I do this?

I have a `UITextField` name in FirstViewController and would like to be able to do something like `firstViewController.name.text = @"new name";` inside of SecondViewController with a button and have the value changed so that if I switch tabs back to the FirstViewController I see the change has been made.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How are you switching between your view controllers? Are they in a tabbarcontroller, a navigationcontroller, etc?

Comment: Didn't see this comment. It was tabbedcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1、Set the FirstViewController as the delegate of SecondViewController；
2、Use NSNotificationCenter to notify the change event.

Answer (score 0):

Well to call

```
firstViewController.name.text = @"new name"
```

You just need a reference to your first view controller inside of your second view controller.  There are a number of ways to pass a reference around.  Could go through the app delegate.

**Another option** that doesn't require you to have a reference to the first view controller inside the second view controller is to use [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Then you can have your second view controller observe a notification named say @"namechange" which contains the new name string.

When the button is pressed, you post a notification to the NSNotificationCenter with the new name attached.  All the info is in the link above, or just google NSNotificationCenter for more tutorials and info.